# iTermで画面分割する時に自動的にカレントディレクトリに移動させる方法

Tags: bash, zsh, iterm

iTermを全画面で使っていると画面分割がかなり有効に活用できる。左側でVimなどのエディタでコードを書きながら右上でデバッグ、右下でインタプリタで簡単なサンプルを試したりと非常に便利に使える。

しかしフォルダのネストが深かったりフォルダ数が多いと新しいパネルを開いてcdするのは非常に面倒くさい。

そこで新しいパネルを開く時に自動的にカレントディレクトリに移動させる（zsh, iTermなどの）設定はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTerm の Preferences > Profiles > お使いのプロフィール > General の Reuse previous session's directory にチェックを入れることで実現できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
Advanced Configurationで新しい{タブ,パネル,ウィンドウ}の挙動も設定できますね。助かりました。